# .UNDEPLOYED file - Apache Tomcat and JBoss Server

Tags: apache-http-server, jboss

We have a system running in Apache and Jboss and my issue is it always creates ".UNDEPLOYED" file. And when it happen the webapp is not accessible, my temporary solution is to delete all .UNDEPLOYED files. Hoping that someone can give permanent/better solution/s. Thank you!..

Comment: Try to add a file named `.deployed` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You having a `.undeployed` means you are having some issue with your deployment. and it means there is an issue with your logic which leads to an unsuccessful deployment. When you are having a successful deployment you will have the `.deployed` file.